# Show that D is dense iff D is an infinite set

Tags: general-topology

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb R$. Show that $D$ is dense iff $D$ is an infinite set.

This is my idea for the forward proof. If $D$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, then $cl D=\mathbb R$. This implies that $\exists x\in \mathbb R$ such that for every nbhd $U$ of $x$, $U$  intersect $D$. Thus, $D$ is an infinite set. (Please verify this)

However, in the converse. If $D$ is an infinite set, then D is dense in $\mathbb R$. But if $D=\mathbb Z$? $\mathbb Z$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you are right $D=\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite but not dense.. the claim is wrong.

Comment: $$D=\Bbb N $$ infinite and closed.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot.

Comment: Another way to define a *dense* set is that for any $$a,b\in D, a<b\to \exists c\in D: a<c<b$$therefore it is infinite because if not there would be the last two elements with nothing in between. But an infinite set can be discrete, not dense that is for any $x\in D\,\exists U(x)$ such that $U(x)\cap D=\varnothing$ the opposite of dense...

Comment: This is a classic question missing context. The origin of this claim, as well as some hint as to what you know or don't know, would have made a lot of difference in the number of eyebrows raised by this question. It might have also helped you find the answer before clicking "Post Your Question". By writing out what we know, we put it into some ordered perspective, which is often helpful in finding out the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the converse isn't true.